# MySQL - Count unique views per IP max 1 time per day

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get unique views per IP, counted max 1 time per day returned using a MySQL query.

**The table is looking like this:**

```
product_id          time          ip
INT                 TIMESTAMP     VARCHAR
```

The query should return the unique views for any time, but it should filter product id's so each product have it's own unique views field counted. The IP-address in the table should be counted MAX once per day. I'll give you some details what should and should not be counted in the query below:

```
product_id          DATE(time)          ip            should_be_counted
11                  2012-12-14          1.1.1.1       YES
11                  2012-12-14          1.1.1.2       YES
11                  2012-12-14          1.1.1.1       NO
11                  2012-12-13          1.1.1.1       YES
11                  2012-12-13          1.1.1.1       NO

Should be returned:
product_id          unique_views
11                  3
```

**This is what I want:**

```
product_id          unique_views
11                  103
8                   53
2                   3
1                   1
```

Which means that the query should use ORDER BY unique_views DESC.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT Product_ID, SUM(unique_view) unique_views
FROM
(
  SELECT Product_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT IP)  unique_view
  FROM   tableName
  GROUP BY Product_ID, DATE(time)
) x
GROUP BY Product_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe72b/9)